# User with permission to modify only one field of the model in the Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a user named *ExpertUser* who should only be able to modify an attribute of the called model (money) of the users in the Django Admin.

I have tried adding permissions in the model using the *Meta* but when entering with that permission *I can not modify anything since I do not have access to any user*.

My model is this:

---

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    money = models.FloatField(default=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_view_money", "Can view money"),)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Django Guardian. That provides more flexibility in assigning permissions on various levels. Django only lets you set permissions at object level, so in your case you were only able to set permission to create/edit/delete Client objects.

http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.8/index.html

If that doesn't suffice, there are a few other packages with the desired functionality:

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/perms/