# Allow non-superadmin users to reset the password for another user in django admin

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, django-authentication

I am working on a third party app running django 2.2.12.

I have an admin with 3 kinds of users: "superadmin", "staff" and "other".

When I am logged as "superadmin", when I go to the Users list and click on a user, I am able to edit them and reset their password.

However, when I try to do the same as a "staff" user, I can see the user data, but can't edit anything, and there's no option to reset the password. If I try to access the URL manually (`/admin/accounts/user/[USER_ID]/password/`) I get a "403 Forbidden" error message.

I noticed that if I override the `has_perm` method in the user model, it allows the "staff" user to edit the user data. However I would like to allow only the password change (if the user is not a superadmin or a staff user), without allowing "staff" users to edit other users.

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return True
```

I have the impression this has to do with the Django permission system, but I re-read the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/ and couldn't figure this out yet.

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need the use of a package
[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954428/11769955)

Comment: @ShubhamYadav Thanks. I will take a look

Would it be possible to programatically allow the "staff" users to edit the Users, but hide all its properties, except for the password? I believe this workaround would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to make it work with a less than ideal solution, but did the trick.

Basically I overload the `has_change_permission` method of the `UserAdmin` class and add a custom logic to allow the password change in a special case (url ends with '/password' and user has the correct permissions.

```
    def can_edit_password(self, logged_user, chosen_user=None):
        if logged_user and logged_user.is_superuser:
            return True

        logged_user_has_change_pass_perm = (
            logged_user and
            logged_user.is_authenticated and
            logged_user.has_perm("accounts.change_student_password")
        )
        return logged_user_has_change_pass_perm

    def can_show_change_password_form(self, path, logged_user, chosen_user=None):
        is_changing_password = path.endswith('/password/')
        return is_changing_password and self.can_edit_password(logged_user, chosen_user)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, user=None):
        if self.can_show_change_password_form(path=request.path, logged_user=request.user, chosen_user=user):
            return True
        return super(UserAdmin, self).has_change_permission(request, user)
```